# Returning different elements between a Hashtable and list<string> in F#

Tags: f#

I have two collections:

1. A list of strings
2. A hashtable

```
let properties = [
    "First";
    "Second"
  ]
let hash = System.Collections.Hashtable ()
  hash.Add("First", "Blub")
  hash.Add("Third", "Blob")
```

My goal is to find the key which is not in the `properties` list.
My solution is so far:

```
// Casting my hashtable to a sequence to work with it easier
let keys:seq<string> = hash.Keys |> Seq.cast

// Casting the sequence to a set to get the difference in the end
let setAll = Set.ofSeq keys

// Getting all elements which are also in the properties list
let validKeySeq = Seq.filter (fun elem -> List.contains elem properties) keys

// Casting the sequence to a set to get the difference in the following line
let validKeys = Set.ofSeq validKeySeq

// Getting the element which is not in the list
Set.difference setAll validKeys
```

The above code works but is there a clearer, more concise or more idiomatic way of getting the element which is not in the list?

Comment: I'm not sure why there is a down vote here, but a guess would be because you have `How can I` in the title. We generally don't answer how to questions on the code review site. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for better ideas on how to title the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct way would be with the [`Seq.except`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-seqmodule.html) function, which returns a new sequence that omits any elements that appear in the other parameter.

```
table.Keys
|> Seq.cast<string>
|> Seq.except properties
```

I've named the hash table `table` rather than `hash`, because a `Hashtable` is a type of table that uses hashes, rather than a hash itself (I call this out, because I see 'hash' used like this quite often, and it's always confusing).

`Seq.cast` is still needed, because we are working with an untyped collection, but removes the complexity in the rest of the implementation: it would be nice to trap the error this throws when there is invalid input and qualify it.

It's fine to give nice names to each step of a computation as you have done (good practise, even), but using a pipeline like this is idiomatic F#.

Note that your implementation uses a linear-scan to check each key of the table against the list of properties; using `Seq.except` leaves the choice of method up to the BCL, but it most likely builds a HashSet from `Properties` and queries against that, which will generally give much better performance (closer to linear rather than quadratic).

Note also that your implementation can be simplified by inverting the filter: you are selecting those keys that are also in `properties`, but you can just as well filter for keys that are *not* properties (with the same cost).

```
let differentKeys = Seq.filter (fun elem -> not (List.contains elem properties)) keys
```

---

Let's package up the implementation nicely in a function, and add some inline documentation (`///`)

```
/// Enumerates all keys of the given table that are not in the sequence of properties
let nonPropertyKeys (table:IDictionary) properties =
    table.Keys
    |> Seq.cast<string>
    |> Seq.except properties
```

We can leave F# to infer the type of `properties` (or qualify it as `seq<string>` if you like) and return type (also `seq<string>`).

Note also that this function doesn't expect a `HashTable` specifically: it will accept any `IDictionary`, which may or may not be a useful generalisation for your scenario.

Generally you should avoid older types like `Hashtable`, and use newer (generic) versions, e.g. `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` (and `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>`), and consider using a standard F# (immutable) collection like `map<'key, 'value>`. I assume your exact scenario doesn't permit this, however.

If we want to trap the `InvalidCastException` for an invalid input table (thrown when any key is not a string), then we need to actualise the result before returning.

```
let nonPropertyKeys (table:IDictionary) (properties:seq<string>) =
    try
        table.Keys
        |> Seq.cast<string>
        |> Seq.except properties
        |> Seq.toList
    with
    | :? InvalidCastException as ice -> raise (ArgumentException(nameof(table), "Table must only have string keys"))
```

This may be important for avoiding confusion, and makes the method more consistent in terms of failure condition with your original code (which also forces evaluation).

Alternatively, I note while your code produces a list, your comment mentions returning 'the key' that is not in `properties`, which you could achieve with the [`Seq.exactlyOne`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-seqmodule.html#exactlyOne) method: this will raise an exception if there are no elements in a collection, or if there is more than one element. It has a non-raising brother [`Seq.tryExactlyOne`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-seqmodule.html#tryExactlyOne) that returns an `option 'a`. Either of these would also force the evaluation of the original sequences.